# Iterating over list and submitting Callables to an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `List` of users that I want to iterate over and create a `Callable` for each that is passed to an `ExecutorService` like so:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();

for(final User user : users) {

    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return doSomethingWithUser(user);
        }
    });

    futures.add( future );      
}

executor.shutdown();

for(Future<String> future : futures) {
    String message = future.get();
    System.out.println(message);        
}
```

I believe this won't work correctly, because the user inside the `call()` method is not the same current user in the iteration when the `Callable` was created. In other words:

```
for(final User user : users) {

    System.out.println("User: " + user.username); // The current user

    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("User: " + user.username); // Might not be the same user as above
            return doSomethingWithUser(user);
        }
    });

    futures.add( future );      
}
```

To fix this, I created a `MyCallable` class that implements `Callable` and allows for a constructor

```
public abstract class MyCallable<I, O> implements Callable<O> {

    private I param;

    public MyCallable(I param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    public I getParam() {

        return param;
    }
}
```

Then in my iterator, I pass the user argument to the constructor

```
for(final User user : users) {

    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new MyCallable<User, String>(user) {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return doSomethingWithUser(user);
        }
    });

    futures.add( future );                  
}
```

This works, but I'm curious if instead of creating a new class called `MyCallable` I could just use the `Callable` as an anonymous inner class as I was before. However, I would instead add a member variable to it.

```
for(final User user : users) {

    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        private User _user = user;
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return doSomethingWithUser(_user);
        }
    });

    futures.add( future );      
}
```

Would this work fine? I've tested it, and it seems to work, but I can be kind of difficult to know with multithreading. Member variables are initialized before the constructor, so in theory my `_user` variable, should have the correct user, right?

Comment: Your original code is fine. The value of `user` is implicitly captured in an "anonymous" field of the anonymous class instance.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks! That's what I thought. I must have had a bug somewhere else then.

Comment: Did your initial code **actually** fail? You say "might fail...", but as Sotirios mentions, it was just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work just fine the way it was originally. Variables used in an anonymous class/lambda are captured when the anonymous class is defined - this is why Java requires them to be effectively final - so you don't need to worry, the value of `user` will still be the same when the callable runs.